# Monit: ping a website url then restart application server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monit

I am using this configuration for monitoring apache2 (ubuntu):

*/etc/monit/conf.d/apache2*:

```
check process apache with pidfile /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid

    start program = "/etc/init.d/apache2 start" with timeout 60 seconds
    stop program  = "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop"

    alert f.bozzo@3-w.it with mail-format {
            from: monit@3-w.it
            subject: monit alert: $SERVICE $EVENT $DATE
            message: $DESCRIPTION
    }

    if failed port 80 protocol HTTP
            request /
            with timeout 7 seconds
            then restart
```

Accessing  'request /' results in the ubuntu-apache default page: if you can reach it, then Apache is working. And that's ok.

Now I need to monitor my application server, too. 
So I have a second configuration file:

```
check process lucee with pidfile /opt/lucee/tomcat/work/tomcat.pid

        start program = "/etc/init.d/lucee_ctl start" with timeout 60 seconds
        stop program  = "/etc/init.d/lucee_ctl stop"
```

I don't know exactly how to tell monit to request a fully qualified URI, I need something like

```
if failed port 80 protocol HTTP
            request http://www.xxxxxx123123.com/
            with timeout 7 seconds
            then restart
```

but that says

> /etc/monit/conf.d/lucee:13: Error: syntax error '

on reload.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on sample

```
  if failed host localhost port 80 with protocol http and request "/server-status" with timeout 25 seconds for 4 times within 5 cycles then restart
```

try to put instead

```
  if failed host www.xxxxxx123123.com port 80 with protocol http 
      and request "/" 
      with timeout 7 seconds 
      then restart
```